# the purpose of cakePHP Model parentNode() function?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3, acl

I sometimes see the function `parentNode()` in cakePHP models. What is the purpose of that function and when should I use it? If I don't use it, what problems am I going to encounter.

On [this website](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/545/Using-the-AclBehavior), they say that you need it so that your model can have ACL behaviors, but what if I just run the [`build_acl`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1549/An-Automated-tool-for-creating-ACOs) command after creating my Model, isn't that the same thing? Can someone shed some light on this please?

Thank you

Comment: You tagged this question cakephp-1.3, but your links are to the book for cakephp-1.2.  Which version are you actually using (1.2 to 1.3 was a pretty big upgrade)?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the links, I'm using version 1.3

Answer (score 2):

`build_acl()` is useful as a one-time execution to populate your acl tables with the current controllers+actions.  This is useful as a base to get you started.

`parentNode()` is called by the model behaviour in afterSave() to maintain the hiearchy during the life of your application. So when you manually (or dynamically) add AROs / ACOs later on (e.g. 5 months from now) everything will still work. Especially true if you add ACOs with custom aliases.

BTW, best ACL tutorial I've found:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists/